# TFlite object detector app crashes just before making predictions

Tags: android, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

I tried several methods to deploy the tflite model on android, flutter, kotlin, etc, but andriod app keeps crashing when I want to make predictions. This was an error I got trying out the object detection codelab:

```
2022-01-01 15:52:55.965 2971-3034/org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection, PID: 2971
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAssetFd(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:938)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils.createHandleFromFdAndOptions(TaskJniUtils.java:65)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.createFromFileAndOptions(ObjectDetector.java:147)
        at org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection.MainActivity.runObjectDetection(MainActivity.kt:127)
        at org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection.MainActivity.access$runObjectDetection(MainActivity.kt:48)
        at org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection.MainActivity$setViewAndDetect$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:150)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
2022-01-01 15:52:56.014 2971-3034/org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2971 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue was caused by android compressing the tflite model during the build. To solve this issue i had to instruct aapt not to compress the file.

go to `build.gradle`, at the app level, inside the `andriod{}` block, add

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "model.tflite"
}
```

please rename `model.tflite` to your custom name if your tflite model is not named "model.tflite"